# Casting entities JPA 2, Spring 3

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

Hi all im having trouble extending entities and persisting them to the data base, my model is has folows,

People    - Base entities, which has to be persisted 
  Friend  - leaf entities 
  Coworker - leaf entities

the problem arise when i get a person from the data base and then i want to "Make it" a friend, instead is creating another People row with the same values, and i want to take the existing one.

Im using join strategy has my inheritance strategy.

any clues ??

Answer (score 2):

I bet what do you mean by "leaf entity" is "Friend and Coworker inherit People", right?

What you are trying to achieve is not suitable to use inheritance.

Just think in a plain OO way:

You have instantiated a "Person" (as suggested by other comment, it is more reasonable to use Person instead of People), you cannot make that instance become a "Friend".

You should consider making Friend / Coworker separate entities, and treat them as extra attributes that a Person carries. e.g.

```
@Entity
class Person {
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="people")
  FriendAttribute friendAttribute;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="people")
  CoworkerAttribute coworkerAttribute;
}


@Entity
class FriendAttribute {
  @OneToOne
  Person person;

  // other friend-related attributes

}

@Entity
class CoworkerAttribute {
  @OneToOne
  Person person;

  // other coworker-related attributes

}
```

By such way, if you want to make a Person being a Coworker, you are going to assign Coworker Attribute to that Person.

Honestly this question have nothing to do with Hibernate or JPA.  It simply doesn't work in plain POJO too, as what I suggested before.  In Java, you simply cannot make an instance of a class become instance of another class.

Comment: Excellent points. Also I'd consider renaming your People class to Person. After all the class represents one person, not multiple. :-)

Comment: Agree for the naming.  In fact I am just following the original post's naming... Honestly I don't even think "Friend" is a good name in such case... :P  Lemme fix a bit on them anyway

Comment: thx all for the comments, i think my problem was on the concept of join strategy for inheritance, since the pk on the child entities will be both a PK and FK to the parent table. PS: when i refer to "Make it", i mean save a record on the table "Friend", with all the data on "Person" table

Comment: When working with Hibernate/JPA etc, unless u really need to cope with legacy DB schema, never design using the aspect of DB.  There are lots of way that works "fine" in RMDBS world that makes OO model a mess (your case is a good example).  Think in OO way and translate your model to DB table instead.